# String is being treated as variable in `eval` statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, undefined

I'm trying to do an extremely simple pass-in of a string variable into my `eval` statement. However, my string is being treated as an undefined variable.

Here is my code:

```
condition = 'hi'
print(eval("2 + 4 * len(%s)" % (condition)))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(eval("4 + 3 * len(%s)" % (condition)))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
```

---

However, when I define `hi` as if it were a variable, all the sudden the code compiles and runs:

```
condition = 'hi'
hi = 'hi'
print(eval("2 + 4 * len(%s)" % (condition)))
```

Output:

```
10
```

What in the world? This seems totally unintuitive to me. Could someone help me define `condition` in a way that Python does not ask for `'hi'` to be defined as well?

Answer (score 1):

That %s will get replaced with `hi`. So you are asking python to run the code:

```
eval("2 + 4 * len(hi)")
```

`len(hi)` will look for a variable named "hi". What you want is `len('hi')` or `len(condition)`. Here are a few alternatives that should work:

```
# Simplest
print(eval("2 + 4 * len(condition)"))

# Repr gives you the string representation of the object, including quotes
print(eval("2 + 4 * len(%s)" % (repr(condition))))

# Assuming condition doesn't contain '
print(eval("2 + 4 * len('%s')" % (condition)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're replacing %s with 'hi'.

Try executing len(hi) will result the same NameError exception as hi is not defined.

```
print(eval("2 + 4 * len(\"%s\")" % condition))
```

will do the job.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Uv9.png)

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing `hi` as a string

```
>>> condition = "'hi'"
>>> print(eval("2 + 4 * len(%s)" % (condition)))
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around %s, like so:

```
condition = 'hi'
print(eval("2 + 4 * len('%s')" % (condition)))
```

This way you are passing len() a string 'hi' instead of a variable hi.